# Problems connecting to Raspberry Pi 3B+ using USB to Serial

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, macos-catalina, usbserial

I am trying to set up SSH over USB to Serial. 
I am using:
- MacBook Pro (OS X 10.15.1)
- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ (Raspbian 9.11)
- EVISWIY PL2303TA USB to TTL Serial Cable Debug Console Cable for Raspberry Pi 3 ([Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D9R5JFK))

I have installed the cable driver however i did notice when i downloaded it that they did not mention support for the Catalina OS ([Driver Download](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41)) however it does list support for High Sierra 10.15...

Cable is plugged in as so (Im colorblind so just making sure i didn't make a mistake there):
[image: Pinout]

I am running `ls /dev` and getting back as follows:

```
afsc_type5          pf
auditpipe           pfm
auditsessions           profile
autofs              ptmx
autofs_control          ptyp0
autofs_homedirmounter       ptyp1
autofs_notrigger        ptyp2
autofs_nowait           ptyp3
bpf0                ptyp4
bpf1                ptyp5
bpf10               ptyp6
bpf100              ptyp7
bpf101              ptyp8
bpf102              ptyp9
bpf103              ptypa
bpf104              ptypb
bpf105              ptypc
bpf106              ptypd
bpf107              ptype
bpf108              ptypf
bpf109              ptyq0
bpf11               ptyq1
bpf110              ptyq2
bpf111              ptyq3
bpf112              ptyq4
bpf113              ptyq5
bpf114              ptyq6
bpf115              ptyq7
bpf116              ptyq8
bpf117              ptyq9
bpf118              ptyqa
bpf119              ptyqb
bpf12               ptyqc
bpf120              ptyqd
bpf121              ptyqe
bpf122              ptyqf
bpf123              ptyr0
bpf124              ptyr1
bpf125              ptyr2
bpf126              ptyr3
bpf127              ptyr4
bpf128              ptyr5
bpf129              ptyr6
bpf13               ptyr7
bpf130              ptyr8
bpf131              ptyr9
bpf132              ptyra
bpf133              ptyrb
bpf134              ptyrc
bpf135              ptyrd
bpf136              ptyre
bpf137              ptyrf
bpf138              ptys0
bpf139              ptys1
bpf14               ptys2
bpf140              ptys3
bpf141              ptys4
bpf142              ptys5
bpf143              ptys6
bpf144              ptys7
bpf145              ptys8
bpf146              ptys9
bpf147              ptysa
bpf148              ptysb
bpf149              ptysc
bpf15               ptysd
bpf150              ptyse
bpf151              ptysf
bpf152              ptyt0
bpf153              ptyt1
bpf154              ptyt2
bpf155              ptyt3
bpf156              ptyt4
bpf157              ptyt5
bpf158              ptyt6
bpf159              ptyt7
bpf16               ptyt8
bpf160              ptyt9
bpf161              ptyta
bpf162              ptytb
bpf163              ptytc
bpf164              ptytd
bpf165              ptyte
bpf166              ptytf
bpf167              ptyu0
bpf168              ptyu1
bpf169              ptyu2
bpf17               ptyu3
bpf170              ptyu4
bpf171              ptyu5
bpf172              ptyu6
bpf173              ptyu7
bpf174              ptyu8
bpf175              ptyu9
bpf176              ptyua
bpf177              ptyub
bpf178              ptyuc
bpf179              ptyud
bpf18               ptyue
bpf180              ptyuf
bpf181              ptyv0
bpf182              ptyv1
bpf183              ptyv2
bpf184              ptyv3
bpf185              ptyv4
bpf186              ptyv5
bpf187              ptyv6
bpf188              ptyv7
bpf189              ptyv8
bpf19               ptyv9
bpf190              ptyva
bpf191              ptyvb
bpf192              ptyvc
bpf193              ptyvd
bpf194              ptyve
bpf195              ptyvf
bpf196              ptyw0
bpf197              ptyw1
bpf198              ptyw2
bpf199              ptyw3
bpf2                ptyw4
bpf20               ptyw5
bpf200              ptyw6
bpf201              ptyw7
bpf202              ptyw8
bpf203              ptyw9
bpf204              ptywa
bpf205              ptywb
bpf206              ptywc
bpf207              ptywd
bpf208              ptywe
bpf209              ptywf
bpf21               random
bpf210              rdisk0
bpf211              rdisk0s1
bpf212              rdisk0s2
bpf213              rdisk0s3
bpf214              rdisk1
bpf215              rdisk1s1
bpf216              rdisk1s2
bpf217              rdisk1s3
bpf218              rdisk1s4
bpf219              rdisk1s5
bpf22               rdisk2
bpf220              sdt
bpf221              stderr
bpf222              stdin
bpf223              stdout
bpf224              systrace
bpf225              tty
bpf226              tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
bpf227              tty.usbserial
bpf228              tty.usbserial-1420
bpf229              ttyp0
bpf23               ttyp1
bpf230              ttyp2
bpf231              ttyp3
bpf232              ttyp4
bpf233              ttyp5
bpf234              ttyp6
bpf235              ttyp7
bpf236              ttyp8
bpf237              ttyp9
bpf238              ttypa
bpf239              ttypb
bpf24               ttypc
bpf240              ttypd
bpf241              ttype
bpf242              ttypf
bpf243              ttyq0
bpf244              ttyq1
bpf245              ttyq2
bpf246              ttyq3
bpf247              ttyq4
bpf248              ttyq5
bpf249              ttyq6
bpf25               ttyq7
bpf250              ttyq8
bpf251              ttyq9
bpf252              ttyqa
bpf253              ttyqb
bpf254              ttyqc
bpf255              ttyqd
bpf26               ttyqe
bpf27               ttyqf
bpf28               ttyr0
bpf29               ttyr1
bpf3                ttyr2
bpf30               ttyr3
bpf31               ttyr4
bpf32               ttyr5
bpf33               ttyr6
bpf34               ttyr7
bpf35               ttyr8
bpf36               ttyr9
bpf37               ttyra
bpf38               ttyrb
bpf39               ttyrc
bpf4                ttyrd
bpf40               ttyre
bpf41               ttyrf
bpf42               ttys0
bpf43               ttys000
bpf44               ttys001
bpf45               ttys002
bpf46               ttys003
bpf47               ttys004
bpf48               ttys1
bpf49               ttys2
bpf5                ttys3
bpf50               ttys4
bpf51               ttys5
bpf52               ttys6
bpf53               ttys7
bpf54               ttys8
bpf55               ttys9
bpf56               ttysa
bpf57               ttysb
bpf58               ttysc
bpf59               ttysd
bpf6                ttyse
bpf60               ttysf
bpf61               ttyt0
bpf62               ttyt1
bpf63               ttyt2
bpf64               ttyt3
bpf65               ttyt4
bpf66               ttyt5
bpf67               ttyt6
bpf68               ttyt7
bpf69               ttyt8
bpf7                ttyt9
bpf70               ttyta
bpf71               ttytb
bpf72               ttytc
bpf73               ttytd
bpf74               ttyte
bpf75               ttytf
bpf76               ttyu0
bpf77               ttyu1
bpf78               ttyu2
bpf79               ttyu3
bpf8                ttyu4
bpf80               ttyu5
bpf81               ttyu6
bpf82               ttyu7
bpf83               ttyu8
bpf84               ttyu9
bpf85               ttyua
bpf86               ttyub
bpf87               ttyuc
bpf88               ttyud
bpf89               ttyue
bpf9                ttyuf
bpf90               ttyv0
bpf91               ttyv1
bpf92               ttyv2
bpf93               ttyv3
bpf94               ttyv4
bpf95               ttyv5
bpf96               ttyv6
bpf97               ttyv7
bpf98               ttyv8
bpf99               ttyv9
console             ttyva
cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port  ttyvb
cu.usbserial            ttyvc
cu.usbserial-1420       ttyvd
disk0               ttyve
disk0s1             ttyvf
disk0s2             ttyw0
disk0s3             ttyw1
disk1               ttyw2
disk1s1             ttyw3
disk1s2             ttyw4
disk1s3             ttyw5
disk1s4             ttyw6
disk1s5             ttyw7
disk2               ttyw8
dtrace              ttyw9
dtracehelper            ttywa
fbt             ttywb
fd              ttywc
fsevents            ttywd
io8log              ttywe
io8logmt            ttywf
io8logtemp          urandom
klog                vboxdrv
lockstat            vboxdrvu
machtrace           vboxnetctl
null                xcpm
oslog               zero
oslog_stream
```

So... from that result and consulting many guides for accomplishing this task i have been trying to use the `screen` command on the following:

- cu.usbserial-1420
- cu.usbserial
- tty.usbserial-1420
- tty.usbserial

I've been running it as follows:

```
screen /dev/[INSERT ONE HERE] 115200
```

that seems to be the baud rate suggested in multiple guides but I've also tried 9600 and 115600 as I saw those both mentioned in regards to RPi's a few times.

The best result i ever get is an empty terminal window with the cursor grey block:
[image: bad result]

I've tried disabling System Integrity Protection because one Adafruit tutorial mentioned it. No change.

Also i have enabled serial interface in the `raspi-config` menu

Any Direction to my problem would be greatly appreciated. Im getting the feeling its the driver because i can't find any other ideas... but i am hoping that's not the case.

--EDIT--

I read somewhere that [This Driver](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers) is the correct one for newer models of this device. After install there is no change.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test know, but double check [this guide](https://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection), perhaps a configuration gotcha ? FWIW I had a look at the photo you've sent and based on the amazon link and the RPi pinout you're wiring looks legit (converter GND, RX, TX connected to RPI GND, TX, RX)

Comment: `tty.usbserial-1420` looks like it should be you're port, maybe `tty.usbserial` is an alias ? Eitherway,it might be worth connecting it to a microcontroller or something to check that sending/receiving works with that converter and you weren't unlucky to get a dodgy one accidentally from a bad batch. If that works, you can also test reading some bytes/characters send from your mac to the RPi with a basic python script (using pyserial).(The idea is to isolate the problem: it it with the converter or with the pi configuration)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza unfortunately went through that guide already. i don't see any equivalent to the "dialout" group for OS X but other than that I've done it all. i agree that `tty.usbserial-1420` looks to be the correct port, and unfortunately i don't have any microcontrollers on hand...

Comment: Would it be possible to open the port on OSX and send character `'a'` every second and on the Raspberry Pi side open the internal UART port to which the RX/TX belong to and read continuously ? The point of the test is to test OSX to RPi serial communication. If that works it's worth swapping scripts so RPi sends the char and OSX reads it. If both tests work then there's no problem with the serial converter and no major issue on the RPi side: it will be down to how that port is configured with the OS to output it's console...

Comment: ...If it doesn't then it might be worth testing on a swapping the Pi for another computer. You can also test with something else like CoolTerm instead of `screen` with the default 8N1 config (8 data-bits, 1 stop-bit, no parity)